# Count number of Rows in Google Sheets that have a date column that contain a certain year

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I've tried using some of the recommended solutions, such as

```
=arrayformula(COUNTIF((WEEKNUM($G$4:$G) = 10)* (YEAR($G$4:$G) = 2020),1))
```

which counts the week number and year, but taking out week number doesn't work.   I've also tried using chatGPT and chat GPT gives me what I already tried, which was

```
=COUNTIF($G$4:$G, "*2020")
```

I've also tried

```
=COUNTIF(text($G$4:$G,"mm/yyyy"), "*2020")
```

and that doesn't work either. (I get 0 for all of them)

I have a column in google sheets that has a date, written like

```
5/1/2020
5/5/2020
6/1/2021
```

for "Month, Day, Year"   I want to try and count the number of rows for each year, such as 2 for 2020, 1 for 2021, etc.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit and as soon as I ask, i solve it myself:

```
=arrayformula(COUNTIFS(YEAR(A3:A40), 2019))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `QUERY()` function.

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A1:A,"select year(A) where A is not null label year(A) ''"),
"select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1) ''")
```

[image]